# struct member gets overwritten by garbage value after successful initialization

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I've been debugging this function for quite a while now and can't wrap my head around what could be going on with this piece of code.

```
    void make_points(DocSpec instance, Tree *myTree, Point *p){
int i, j, k, index = 0;

for(i = 0; i < instance.numPt; i++)
    {
        p[i].x = instance.xCoordinates[i];
        p[i].y = instance.yCoordinates[i];
        p[i].parent = myTree[i].parent;
        p[i].num_children = 0;
        for(k = 0; k < MAX_NUM_CHILDREN; k++)
            {
                p[i].child[k] = 0;
            }
        for(j = 0; j < instance.numPt; j++)
            {
                if((i != j) && (myTree[j].parent == i))
                    {
                        p[i].num_children++;
                        p[i].child[index] = j;
                        index++;
                    }
            }
         p[i].overlap_hv = -1;
         p[i].overlap_vh = -1;
         index = 0;
     }

printf("p[1].index = %d;\n", p[1].index);
printf("p[1].x = %d;\n", p[1].x);
printf("p[1].y = %d;\n", p[1].y);
printf("p[1].parent = %d;\n", p[1].parent);
printf("p[1].num_children = %d;\n", p[1].num_children);

printf("p[1].child[8] = {");
index = 0;
for(i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_CHILDREN; i++)
    {
        if(p[1].child[i] != 0 && index == 0)
            {
                printf("%d", p[1].child[i]);
            }
        elseif(p[1].child[i] != 0)
            printf(", %d", p[1].child[i]);
    }
print("};\n");
printf("p[1].overlap_hv = %d;\n", p[1].overlap_hv);
printf("p[1].overlap_vh = %d;\n", p[1].overlap_vh);
}
```

The output I'm getting after running the function is the following:

```
p[1].index = 1;
p[1].x = 0;
p[1].y = 90;
p[1].parent = 5;
p[1].num_children = 0;
p[1].child[8] = {1563515760, 1768448814, 945513580, 540876893};
p[1].overlap_hv = 909455739;
p[1].overlap_vh = 892679225;
```

But it should be:

```
p[1].index = 1;
p[1].x = 0;
p[1].y = 90;
p[1].parent = 5;
p[1].num_children = 0;
p[1].child[8] = {};
p[1].overlap_hv = -1;
p[1].overlap_vh = -1;
```

When I ran gdb on my program, I noticed that the values of p[1] are initialized properly, but when

```
printf("p[1].x = %d;\n", p[1].x);
```

is executed - p[1].child[4], p[1].child[5], p[1].child[6], p[1].child[7], p[1].overlap_hv, p[1].overlap_vh all get overwritten with the garbage values.

I have no idea why or how a printf statement could change the values of my struct members.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use C and C++ tag? Choose one.

Comment: A wild guess is that the code writes out-of-bounds somewhere. What does a `Point`look like, and how is the space for the points and their children allocated?

Comment: Since the code is not complete it is difficult to reproduce the error. I can guess that `p` is not a pointer to the first element of an array, but to a single `Point` and that `p[1]` doesn't exist and points to some random garbage memory. But it's just a guess because I can't see the code.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here's a debugging suggestion:  put a printf("Ctor %p\n", this); in each of your Point class's constructors, and a printf("Dtor %p\n", this);  in your Point class's destructor.  Then put a printf("p is at %p\n", &p[1]); at the point where the problem occurs.  Then run the program, and go through the output to see if p was a valid Point object at the time your symptom occurs.  My bet is that it was either never valid at that location, or was destroyed earlier; either way you're dereferencing an invalid pointer and that's why the memory at that location changes unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't use the proper typecast when reallocating memory. A quick check with Valgrind led me right to the culprit.

had

```
p = (Point*) realloc(p, instance.numPt * sizeof(p));
```

and this fixed it

```
p = (Point*) realloc(p, instance.numPt * sizeof(Point));
```

Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `index` is crossing child boundary and `j` overwrites next struct members   `p[1].overlap_hv` and `p[1].overlap_vh`:

```
                    p[i].child[index] = j;
                    index++;
```